# Converting to Unix Timestamps from mixed Strings

Tags: php, timestamp, strtotime

Today I am looking for some help with an update I am making to my database. In the previous version of our internal system we used the following styled strings as system logs;

```
User Admin Logged in from xx.xx.xx.xx - 24/05/2014 - 12:26PM
```

All times are written to the database in a single string as above, however I am looking to modernize the system and use timestamps so that searches can be done on them. There are several thousand records in the database, all with the time marker as above.

I am looking for assistance in breaking the string, extracting the time and then converting it to a timestamp, saving it to a database thereafter.

So far I have tried to use the following manually just to see what results;

```
strtotime($string . " UTC+10");
```

Using terms such as 'now' and 'today' and 'June 31st' seem to work, however the string of '24/05/2014 - 12:26PM' does not.

In addition to that issue, it has come to my attention that the use of / between the date information will then force the script to read it as mm/dd/yyyy instead of dd/mm/yyyy

What is the advised way to proceed, remembering I want to extract these from a database, get the timestamp, save it back to the database all automatically. Server load isnt an issue as it only needs to occur once.

Thank you greatly as always :)

---

I used the following code based on the answer provided to accomplish this quickly and efficiently. Hope it helps others!

```
<?php
    require_once("config.inc.php");

    $ProcessText = '';
    $QueryCount = 0;
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE(RIGHT(log,20), '%d/%m/%Y - %h:%i%p')),dbid FROM systemlogs WHERE `timestamp` = '';");
    while($data = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
        $doupdate = mysql_query("UPDATE `systemlogs` SET `timestamp` = '".$data[0]."' WHERE `dbid` = '".$data[1]."' LIMIT 1");
        $ProcessText .= 'Updated: '.$data[1].' | Set Timestamp: '.$data[0];
        $QueryCount++;
    }

    //echo $ProcessText;
    echo '<strong>Total Queries Run: '.$QueryCount.'</strong>';

?>
```

Comment: look at [date_create_from_format()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-create-from-format.php)

Comment: are you looking for a PHP solution or a database one? (what database? mySQL?)

Comment: I am looking for either a PHP or MySQL, whichever would be a cleaner solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, if you're looking for a database solution and it's mySQL you could construct an update statement using this:

```
select UNIX_TIMESTAMP( STR_TO_DATE('24/05/2014 - 12:26PM', '%d/%m/%Y - %h:%i%p') );
```

What you'd want to do is use SUBSTR or some other function to grab the timestamp part from the column you've stored this log information in, then convert it like the above, and then use an UPDATE statement combined with that select.

Here's a full example:

```
create database so1;
use so1;

create table logs ( old varchar(128), new bigint(20));
INSERT INTO logs (old) VALUES ('User Admin Logged in from xx.xx.xx.xx - 24/05/2014 - 12:26PM');
INSERT INTO logs (old) VALUES ('User Admin Logged in from xx.xx.xx.xx - 24/05/2014 - 12:27PM');
INSERT INTO logs (old) VALUES ('User Admin Logged in from xx.xx.xx.xx - 24/05/2014 - 12:28PM');

update logs a left join (SELECT  UNIX_TIMESTAMP ( STR_TO_DATE( RIGHT(old, 20), '%d/%m/%Y - %h:%i%p') ) as new, old FROM logs) b on a.old=b.old   set a.new = b.new;
```

**How it works:**

I'm making the assumption that your log strings last 20 characters are always the timestamp you're trying to get. So, the SQL function `RIGHT(str,n)` will return the rightmost `n` characters of some `str` of data. In this case, the `old` column in my example.

So: `RIGHT('User Admin Logged in from xx.xx.xx.xx - 24/05/2014 - 12:26PM', 20)` will return `24/05/2014 - 12:26PM`

Next, we need to convert that string into a time that mysql can understand. The mySQL function `STR_TO_TIME` is made for this. It takes two arguments: the first is the string you're going to convert (the output of our `RIGHT` function, and then the second argument is the format that will be parsed out.  In this case, `%d/%m/%Y - %h:%i%p` , you can find a [list of what each of those mean here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) but its the day/month/Year a space and a dash, then the hour colin, minutes AM|PM. So, mySQL will take your string and convert it. If you just run `STR_TO_TIME` + `RIGHT` you'll get a datetime column back, but you said you want a timestamp...

So finally we get to the last step of the conversion, which is simply ask mySQL to convert it the datetime object to a timestamp with `UNIX_TIMESTAMP`. And bam, there's the value you want.

Next up is the actual update, this is so you can do this all in one sweep. There exists something called an "update join" for mySQL (and most sql's I believe). The syntax is:

UPDATE table1  LEFT JOIN table2  ON .field = .field SET .somefield =

So we want to update our log table (in the example) with the results of the conversion being done to the column. So we perform a JOIN with the table and the results of our conversion. In order to join the tables and make sure things match we pull out the `old` column from our new results as well. That's a lot of words so in code:

```
UPDATE logs a 
    LEFT JOIN (...) b ON a.old=b.old 
SET a.new = b.new;
```

I've omitted the query to get the results so that you can more easily see the update syntax. So all we need after this point is the results themselves to join against, which using the conversion process above, and the fact that we need to have the old column to join against we combine:

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE(RIGHT(old,20), '%d/%m/%Y - %h:%i%p')) AS new, old FROM logs
```

and the update query to get the final:

```
UPDATE logs a 
    LEFT JOIN (
         SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE(RIGHT(old,20), '%d/%m/%Y - %h:%i%p')) AS new, old FROM logs
    ) b ON a.old=b.old 
SET a.new = b.new;
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for your detailled response, unfortunatly I do not follow the progression of the code, is there any way you could explain what is happening so I can? I obviously would like to learn as opposed to just copy and pasting your work. Thanks =)

Comment: @Tarquin updated my answer with a bit more explanation

Comment: Thank you very much, you have made it very easy to follow your code, I appreciate it. I will try to employ this and see how it goes

Comment: No problem, if it works out for you accept the answer :) If not comment back. Also, before running that update query it might be good to test just the `SELECT` bit on your data to make sure it all gets converted right. I made the assumption that all your data has the last 20 characters as the date string, if that's not true you might get some nulls. Just something to watch out for.

Comment: Yes they all do, I will be putting the data into another column in the same table as we transition into the new system (Allows both to run along side).

Comment: Thank you. I have posted the code I used to run the update derived from yours, Some of your code is too new to me to adapt, however the power of PHP helped. Thanks for your assistance.